# Trying to understand proof that continuity of a function is sufficient to show local Lipschitz, and choice of notation for the Jacobian

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

The proof looks pretty straightforward, but with a few hiccups. Two, to be precise, which are restated at the bottom.

Th. For open set $O$, if function $F:O\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ is $C^1$, then $F$ is locally Lipschitz.

Given Proof:
the proof examines the compact ball $O_\epsilon$ of radius $\epsilon$ about arbitrary point $X_0$, and asserts that $O_\epsilon$ is convex, allowing a line segment between points $Y,Z\in O_\epsilon,$ given by $Y+sU$, where $U=Z-Y$, and $s\in [0,1]$.

Letting $\psi(s) = F(Y+sU)$, the proof proceeds to take the derivative, to find
$$\psi'(s) = DF_{Y+sU}(U)$$
Where $DF_X(\cdot)$ is the book's notation for the $n\times n$ Jacobian of $F$ wrt vector $X$. But the choice of notation with $Y+sU$ in the subscript is throwing me for a loop: I'm unsure how to interpret that Jacobian. (Question 1: how should I understand $DF_{Y+sU}(U)$)

The proof continues, Therefore,
$$F(Z)-F(Y) - \psi(1)-\psi(0)$$
$$= \int^1_0\psi'(s)ds$$
$$= \int^1_0DF_{Y+sU}(U)ds$$
Thus,
$$|F(Z) - F(Y)| \le  \int^1_0 K|U|ds = K|Z-Y|$$ 
Thereby satisfying definition of the Lipschitz condition.
But, Question 2: I don't follow why that inequality should hold? That seems wholly unexplained.

Question 1: how should I understand $DF_{Y+sU}(U)$?

Question 2: How does the final inequality hold?

Comment: Although the theorem in the question is fine, the formulation in the title is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$DF_{Y+sU}(U)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $F$ computed at $Y+sU$ and then applied to the vector $U$. For example, for $n=1$ you have
$$
\psi'(s) = F'(Y+sU)U,
$$
using the chain rule.

For the second you have
$$
|DF_{Y+sU}(U)|\le \|DF_{Y+sU}\|\cdot|U|\le K |U|,
$$
where $K$ is an upper bound for the continuous function $s\mapsto \|DF_{Y+sU}\|$ on the compact set $[0,1]$.